# Aligning a custom li bullet with the text

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to increase the size of the bullet point next to a `li` element. The consensus seems to be that the way to do this is to remove the "standard" point, insert a custom one using the `:before` selector, and increase the font size of the inserted point.

Well, this kind of works, but it means the text and the point become misaligned. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ybv4kcv2/) for my code.

Is there a way of resolving this that doesn't just rely on hardcoding in that the text needs to be moved down by however many pixels?

Comment: change `vertical-align: middle;` to `vertical-align: top;` @Cal

Answer (score 3):

Set bullet with `position:absolute`

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
}
ul {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  font-size: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, however the text still appears a noticeable distance above the points for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd display is as an `inline-table` and change the `line-height`.

```css
section{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
}

ul{
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li{
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
li::before{
  content: "\2022";
  font-size: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-table;
  line-height: 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```